# ARCore – SFA file format's parameters

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Looking inside the sfa dele we have some configurations.

One of then is the `metallicFactor`

On the [Google I/O Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzaMMV6w_OE) about Sceneform it's say that it can go from 0 to 255 and we normally should use from 0 to 1.

My first question, on the code we should use: **0, 0.2, 0.4, 1** or **0, 20, 40, 255**?

Second, using one of the [Sceneform Sample](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart) for Android I try to change this values for the Sun in the "solarSystem" sample. But for any go the changes it looks the same. What I'm missing?

Someone has a example from the minimum value to the maximum value to see how it should look (Only changing the metallic factor. without change roughness)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`metallicFactor`** scales ***metallicRoughness*** to control the metallicity of the material:

```
metallicFactor  <float_value>
```

Use `0.0` for non-metallic materials:

```
metallicFactor: 0.0;
```

Use `1.0` for metallic materials:

```
metallicFactor: 1.0; // Normalised 1.0 is similar to 255 in 8-bit color scale
```

> So in the code we need to use: `0.0`, `0.2`, `0.4` and `1.0` respectively.

Hope this helps.